# How to spy on default prop function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a default prop which is a function type but not sure how to do that with Jest mocking or spying:

Trying following test:

```
it("should call default toggle function prop on click of footer button", () => {
            const wrapper = shallow(
                <InfoModal
                    isOpen={true}
                    message="Primary message"
                    secondaryMessage="Secondary message"
                />
            );
            const footerButton = wrapper.find("ModalFooter Button");
            const fn = jest.spyOn(wrapper.props(), "toggle");
            footerButton.simulate("click");
            wrapper.update();
            expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

It says **TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'toggle' of object '[object Object]'** where toggle is a function as default prop of `InfoModal`.

How can we test a function prop which has been set default not user defined.

Comment: you can access a defaultProp like; `InfoModal.defaultProps.function`

Answer (score 3):

You can access the defaultProps like static props;

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

App.defaultProps = {
  check: () => console.log('i am working')
}

App.defaultProps.check()
```

Edited:

You could spy on that like so;

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.defaultProps, 'check');
const RenderedApp = shallow(<App />);
RenderedApp.simulate('click');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

So change this line

```
const fn = jest.spyOn(wrapper.props(), "toggle");
```

To

```
const fn = jest.spyOn(wrapper.defaultProps, "toggle");
```

Will do the trick for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-morning-881ny

Comment: That's fine but how to keep an eye on this function to check if this was called after simulating certain event on the component.

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps